# Resizing one element over another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to re-size an element inside and outside of its parent without interruption. Please [see the example](http://jsfiddle.net/cQFzf/10/).

I assume there are three `<div>` rows and each row has several elements with similar (or different) css properties. E.g.:

```
element-1, element-2, ....... element-6
```

@Edit
***inside resizable :*** please see in the pic. as i am resizing `element-1` within `row-1' and the other siblings adjusted the width. ***i can do it by my own***
[image]

***outside resizable :*** please see the pic. element-1 is re-sized it's length without affecting any dimension of it's parent `row-1` & siblings `element-2` but it affect the others elements e.g. `element-3 & 4` has adjusted the width for `element-1`. ***This is what i wanted to ask & not able to do it.***[image]

Comment: I tried to edit your question, but it is still not a clear cut explanation, at least for me.

Comment: @Shef: please take a look again, i tried better to explain now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to achieve that result. You have to alter CSS (add the following):

```
.row {
    position: relative;
}
.element {
    position: absolute;
    /*Remove the float attribute, which is obsolete*/
}
```

The JavaScript code has also to be altered:

```
$(function(){
    var zIndex = 100;
    $('.element').mouseover(function(){
        var originalHeight = $(this).height();
        $(this).resizable({start: function() {
                   $(this).css('z-index', ++zIndex);
        }, stop: function(){
            /*Horizontal fix*/
            var nxt = $(this).nextAll();
            var width = $(this).position().left + $(this).width();
            var safeWidth = width;
            var root = $(this).parent();
            var thisheight = $(this).height();
            var height = root.height();
            for(var i=0,l=nxt.length;i<l;i++){
                $(nxt[i]).css("left", width+"px");
                width += $(nxt[i]).width();
                if($(nxt[i]).height() > height) safeWidth = width;
            }
            /*Vertical fix*/
            if(thisheight > height || originalHeight > thisheight){
                var nxt = root.nextAll();
                for(var i=0, l=nxt.length; i<l; i++){
                    var tht = nxt[i];
                    if(height >= thisheight){
                        width = 0;
                    } else {
                        width = safeWidth;
                    }
                    height += $(tht).height();
                    if(!/(^|\s)row(\s|$)/.test(tht.className)){
                        continue;
                    }
                    var in_nxt = $(tht).children();
                    for(var j=0,k=in_nxt.length; j<k; j++){
                        $(in_nxt[j]).css("left", width+"px");
                        width += $(in_nxt[j]).width();
                    }
                }
            }
            originalHeight = thisheight;
        }});
       });
    $('.element').each(function(){
        var ths = $(this).prevAll();
        var width = 0;
        for(var i=0,l=ths.length;i<l;i++)width+=$(ths[i]).width();
        $(this).css("left", width+"px")});
});
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/cQFzf/12/

Comment: Thanks Rob. it helps me to sort out the problem.